# How to retrieve custom post type permalink in another cpt?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, metabox

I have a metabox which shows custom post type named `football_player` as dropdown.Now I want retrieve the permalink of this custom post in another custom post named `football_team` template.
 Everything; name, image, squad number, is working fine for me except permalink.
Following is the code:

```
$home_starting_player_names = rwmb_meta( 'pb_select_players', array( 'multiple' => true ) ); ?>

          <?php 
           foreach ( $home_starting_player_names as $home_starting_player ){?>
            <li class ="clearfix" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
            <aside class="starting-player-image clearfix" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><?php  echo get_the_post_thumbnail($home_starting_player); ?></aside>
            <aside class="starting-player-name" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 20px;"><?php  echo get_the_title($home_starting_player); ?></aside>
           <aside class="starting-player-number" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><?php  echo get_post_meta( $home_starting_player, 'pb_squad_number', true );?></aside>
           <aside class="team-match-centre-details">
        <div class="team-match-details" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click for details">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 'football_player' ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by myself:
I used following codes instead of

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 'football_player' ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

**I used this code:**

`<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $home_starting_player ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a`>